# FuelPHP Many to Many

Tags: php, fuelphp

I'm trying to make a relationship in the FuelPHP, but I'm getting the following error:

> Fuel\Core\Database_Exception [ 23000 ]:
>   SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`filmestorrentz`.`filmes_tags`, CONSTRAINT `filmes_tags_filme_id` FOREIGN KEY (`filme_id`) REFERENCES `filmes` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE) with query: "INSERT INTO `filmes_tags` (`filme_id`, `tag_id`) VALUES ('', '1')"

I don't know why but FuelPHP is generating a query with filme_id in blank.

Models: [Model_Filme](http://pastebin.com/rswWW8uZ), [Model_Tag](http://pastebin.com/7mqr9t7N)

In the Model_Filme model I have the function that saves the data from the form:

```
public static function save_filme()
{
    $data = Input::post('data');
    $val = static::validate_filme();

    if ($val->run()) {
        if ($data['id']) {
            $filme = static::find($data['id'])->set($data);
            unset($filme->tags);
        } else {
            $filme = static::forge($data);
        }

        foreach ($data['tags'] as $tag_id) {
            $filme->tags[$tag_id] = Model_Tag::find($tag_id);
        }

        $filme->save(); return array($filme, true, null, null);
    } else {
        return array(static::forge($data), false, $val->error(), $data['tags']);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm using FuelPHP 1.8

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that in my view there is a hidden field in which kept the value of the id to edit the registry, just gave a unset(data['id']). solved!

```
public static function save_filme()
{
    $data = Input::post('data');
    $val = static::validate_filme();

    if ($val->run()) {
        if ($data['id']) {
            $filme = static::find($data['id'])->set($data);
            unset($filme->tags);
        } else {
            unset($data['id']);
            $filme = static::forge($data);
        }

        foreach ($data['tags'] as $tag_id) {
            $filme->tags[$tag_id] = Model_Tag::find($tag_id);
        }

        $filme->save(); return array($filme, true, null, null);
    } else {
        return array(static::forge($data), false, $val->error(), $data['tags']);
    }
}
```